# Dual screen mode on laptop and suspend

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, suspend

I'm using dual screen mode on a Lifebook a531 with external monitor at hdmi.

When I close the lid my laptop didn't go to suspend. Only both screens are blanking. Moving of mouse pointer wakes up an external monitor.
But "suspend" from desktop menu works normally, system goes to suspend.

Is there any way to change it?